# Cirrus CI notify email on failed build

Tags: continuous-integration, cirrus-ci

I have hosted my [source code on github](https://github.com/martinFrank/draw-library) and added a trigger on each check in. When the trigger is triggered, the [Cirrus-CI build tool](https://cirrus-ci.org/) starts to build my component. to achive this, github must be setup properly and each component must have a valid `.cirrus.yml` file, who is responsible for the build setup.

how can i change my config file so that i get a notification whenever my build fails?

Here is my `.cirrus.yml` file:

```
container:
  image: maven:latest

build_task:
  build_script: mvn clean compile test sonar:sonar
```

yes, it is rather short and on the Cirrus-CI help page are [explanations concering email notification](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/notifications/) and [writing conditional tasks](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/writing-tasks/#conditional-task-execution) but **I don't see how i can get the build result and create a condition on that**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is simple as can be:

```
container:
  image: maven:latest

build_task:
  build_script: mvn clean compile test sonar:sonar
  on_failure:
    mail_script: mvn postman:send-mail
```

this requires the [postman mail plugin](http://doc.fortysix.ch/maven/maven-postman-plugin/) in your `pom.xml`.